# Make a custom html page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the following screen with `divs`

[image: ref]

I need the big div which sides up to `Octomber` to be able to move it arround the months and when stacks on a month a form be submitted. Could anyone help me with the html (the div positioning).

Comment: You should use CSS3 grid (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: My favorite month is Octomber. I love it when pumkfin spike lattes come out and the weather gets coofer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.container > div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.december {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.november {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.octomber {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.up {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.down {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="december">December</div>
  <div class="november">November</div>
  <div class="octomber">Octomber</div>
  <div class="up"></div>
  <div class="down"></div>
</div>
```